# two select queries with different where clause on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a table follower and following count..

want to get the count of both in one stored procedure.. is it possible to have two select queries with different where condition on same table possible?

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([val1] int, [val2] int, [val3] int, [val4] int, other int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([val1], [val2], [val3], [val4], other)
VALUES
    (1, 26, 13, 1, 1),
    (2, 13, 26, 1, 1),
(3, 10, 26, 1, 1),
(4, 26, 13, 1, 1),
(5, 14, 26, 1, 1)
;
```

**MY select queries**

```
(select count(*) as following_count from table1 where val2=26)

(select count(*) as follower_count from table1 where val3=26)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE LINK**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd73c/10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN val2=26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS following_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN val3=26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS follower_count
FROM
    table1
```

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you fire both statement using UNION ALL ?

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/union.html

SO:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS following_count FROM table1 WHERE val2=26
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS following_count FROM table1 WHERE val3=26
```

returns two rows with 2 numbers in 1 query.

In two columns do this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS following_count FROM table1 WHERE val2=26) col1
  , (SELECT COUNT(*) AS following_count FROM table1 WHERE val3=26) col2
```

Comment: dont want in two rows .. i want in two columns.

Comment: Edited my post, if you want two columns

Comment: thanks but execution time is bit high..compared to other answer.

Comment: Well I did not know your database so it may take longer then Arions solution. You may try setup a index in val2 and val3 but if the other solutions works anyway for you, you be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add semicolon to your statements...

```
(select count(*) as following_count from table1 where val2=26);

(select count(*) as follower_count from table1 where val3=26);
```