# SQL query Compare two WHERE clauses using same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to compare two sets of data that are stored in the same table.  I am sorry if this is a duplicate SO post, I have read some other posts but have not been able to implement it to solve my problem.

I am running a query to show all Athletes and times for the most recent date (2017-05-20):

```
    SELECT  `eventID`,
    `location`,<BR>
    `date`,
    `barcode`,
    `runner`,
    `Gender`,
    `time` FROM `TableName` WHERE `date`='2017-05-20'
```

I would like to compare the time achieved on the 20th May with the previous time for each athlete.

```
SELECT `time` FROM `TableName` WHERE `date`='2017-05-13'
```

How can I structure my query showing all of the `ATHLETES, TIME on 13th, TIME on 20th`

I have tried some methods such as UNION ALL for example

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: You could use a self `JOIN` to get the desired results.

Comment: Sorry @jarlh I am using MySQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [two select queries with different where clause on same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229661/two-select-queries-with-different-where-clause-on-same-table)

Comment: How do you classify one `Athlete`?

Comment: Will a JOIN work, this would be brilliant. I didn't use JOIN because I thought JOIN was just inbetween two tables.  Could you show me some code for structuring this JOIN please?

Comment: Each `Athlete` has a unique number identifier called `barcode`

Comment: Do you know the dates i.e. the most recent one and the previous one?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the previous time using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT t2.time
        FROM TableName t2
        WHERE t2.runner = t.runner AND t2.eventId = t.eventId AND
              t2.date < t.date
        ORDER BY t2.date DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) prev_time
FROM `TableName` t
WHERE t.date = '2017-05-20';
```

For performance, you want an index on `(runner, eventid, date, time)`.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff, I'm just on lunch at the minute.  I will test your code and rate your comment when it works.  It looks like it will give what i'm looking for

Comment: I have been trying to implement this correlated subquery SQL statement with a lot of different of attempts.  It does not return any errors but the Phpmyadmin page just freezes and doesn't execute.  I will keep trying, I want to accept this answer because i'm sure it must work but I can't yet get it to deliver.